# JQuery block element

Tags: jquery, overlay, prepend

Can not seem to get this code working:

http://jsfiddle.net/fxBEg/13/

What i am trying to do is just to overlay the ... overlay onto the DIV area named "footer" but it doesnt seem to do that at all?

JS code:

```
$('#enableOverlay').live('click',function(event){
    var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"><div id="overlayText"><img src="/img/sendingData.gif"><p class="overlaytxt1">Your data is being saved</p><p class="overlaytxt2">Please wait...</p></div></div>').prependTo('#footer');
    var $footer = $('#footer');
    var $enable = $('#enableOverlay');

    $enable.addClass('active');
    $overlay.fadeIn();
});
```

HTML code:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700'>

<p>Curabitur vel nulla ac justo pharetra aliquet. Phasellus dictum porttitor metus, ut mattis eros sagittis sit amet. Aliquam bibendum velit vitae nisi porttitor sollicitudin. Proin pretium sapien eu lorem tempus convallis. In tincidunt erat quis neque dapibus id lobortis mauris placerat. Aliquam tellus sem, consequat ac faucibus ac, rhoncus eu nunc. Nulla pulvinar malesuada viverra.</p><p>In atat turpis mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus a.at turpis mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus  Cat turpis mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus atat turpis mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus  tat turpis mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus urat turpis mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus piat turpis mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus s at turpis mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus mi, ac luctus quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ac eros felis. In ac eros elit, vitae faucibus nibh. Pellentesque eget ipsum in metus vulputate consequat. Nam odio neque, ullamcorper quis molestie a, eleifend sed diam. Nam tellus ante, venenatis et sodales non, ultrices vel neque. Pellentesque vehicula vulputate condimentum. Integer non leo elit, eget cursus um sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur semper, neque ac placerat suscipit, dolor justo vulputate purus, at tristique sem nisl nec orci.</p>

<div id="footer" style="width: 150px; height: 250px;">
    <a id="enableOverlay" style="color: #39F;">CLICK TO Overlay</a>
    This is a normally placed footer somewhere in your html
    gdf
    gsdfgsdfg
    fgs
    dgf
    dgf
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#overlay {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: white;
opacity: 0.9;
z-index: 20000;
}

#overlayText {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 150px;
    z-index:8001;
}

p.overlaytxt1 {
    line-height:70%;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 5px;
    position:relative;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #47c3d3;
    width: 240px;
    margin-left: 43%;
}

p.overlaytxt2 {
    line-height:70%;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #47c3d3;
    width: 140px;
    margin-left: 51%;
    top: -22px;
}
```

​

What could be the problem?

Comment: Interesting CSS. I think you pasted your JS again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the nearest positioned parent element, which in your case is the document.

To solve your problem, you'll need to make the footer element positioned, which will cause `#overlay`'s `top:0`, `left:0` refer to the top left corners of `#footer`.

```
#footer{
    position:relative;
}
```

I've [added this to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxBEg/14/) so you can see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

If we take some code from last question and some from this one, we get this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PcQm3/).
We set the size, and this time the position of the overlay as well, with plain js. This requires a new function:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if(obj.offsetParent){
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

​
We use it to figure out where the footer is at. The fiddle's short, and probably self explanatory. If not post in comment and I'll give more details.

NOTE:
  Doing it this way means that no matter how you place and/or size the footer the overlay will follow it around. Also this will work properly on all major browsers.

EDIT:

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ3WH/) that adds it from js like you asked for in comments.

Comment: Can you give me a version that has the overlay html inside the JavaScript as my example was? Seems to work better creating the overlay div on the spot instead of having it within the code already.

Comment: @StealthRT Added Link to updated fiddle. If the content of your overlay will be dynamically generated, this approach would be useful. However, if the overlay's content is static the first way is better.

Comment: Is it possible to write the JS using JQuery instead of **getElementById**, **getComputedStyle**, **style.top**, etc etc? It's still not working correctly in IE.

Comment: @StealthRT Which ie version are you using?

Comment: IE9 but Kelvin's code works. Just wanted yours as well since it had the position stuff.